# Get array list from file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have wrote a list in to a file, how can i get it back as old array list.

list looks like this

> ['82294', 'ABDUL', 'NAVAS', 'B', 'M', 'MSCS', 'CUKE', '30',
>       'Kasargod', 'CU', 'Kerala', 'Online', 'PG-QS-12', '15', 'June,',
>       '2013', '12.00', 'Noon', '-', '02.00', 'PM\n', '29']
>
> ['82262', 'ABDUL', 'SHAFWAN', 'T', 'H', 'MSCS', 'CUKE', '30',
>           'Kasargod', 'CU', 'Kerala', 'Online', 'PG-QS-12', '15', 'June,',
>           '2013', '12.00', 'Noon', '-', '02.00', 'PM\n', '29']

when i read the file, it does consider as a string list,
for eg:

consider first list:

var[0][0] should be 82294 not '

i am a python noob,

Comment: Are you able to re-serialize the initial array using [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)?

Comment: Have you serialized or pickled the list before putting it in file or just copied and put it as it is in a file?

Comment: `eval` can achieve the goal though it is not safe. Re-serialize using `pickle` is a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file line by line.  For each line you can then eval it, or use json.loads to unpack it.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is better and safer.

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you just do it by hand ? You'll need to either be sure of the safety of the string or adapt the list comprehension to your needs.

```py
foo = "['4','8','15','16','23','42']"
bar = [token.strip("'") for token in foo[1:-1].split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
firstline=File.readline()  #read one line
firstlist=eval(firstline)
```

now you got first list

```
['82294', 'ABDUL', 'NAVAS', 'B', 'M', 'MSCS', 'CUKE', '30', 'Kasargod', 'CU', 'Kerala', 'Online', 'PG-QS-12', '15', 'June,', '2013', '12.00', 'Noon', '-', '02.00', 'PM\n', '29']
```

by using a loop you can get all the list back

`eval()` is a function it will conver string to python expression